# PHP DOM - Replacing TD tags in a THEAD to TH tags

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to replace all TD tags within a THEAD to TH tags.

I figured using the PHP DOM extension would be best. I'm fairly new at it so I apologise for my lack of knowledge.

I did some searching and found how to replace tag names. However, I couldn't figure out how to only replace tag names within a parent (in this case the THEAD tag). I want to leave the TD's within the TBODY as is.

Here is my code to narrow down to the TD's within the THEAD. That's where I get lost.

How would I change the tag names in THEAD to TH?

```
$html = '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

// create empty document 
$document = new DOMDocument();

// load html
$document->loadHTML(html);

// Get theads
$theads = $document->getElementsByTagName('thead');

// Loop through theads (incase there are more than one!)
for($i=0;$i<$theads->length;$i++) {
    $thead = $theads->item($i);

    // Loop through TR
    foreach ($thead->childNodes AS $tr) {
      if ($tr->nodeName == 'tr') {

          // Loop through TD
          foreach ($tr->childNodes AS $td) {
              if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {

                // Replace this tag

                }
            }

      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have checked the manual, there's this `->replaceChild()` method you can use to replace `td` to `th` tags:

```
$html = '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

// create empty document
$document = new DOMDocument();
// load html
$document->loadHTML($html);
// Get theads
$theads = $document->getElementsByTagName('thead')->item(0); // get thead tag
foreach($theads->childNodes as $tr) { // loop thead rows `tr`
    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td'); // get tds inside trs
    $i = $tds->length - 1;
    while($i > -1) {
        $td = $tds->item($i); // td
        $text = $td->nodeValue; // text node
        $th = $document->createElement('th', $text); // th element with td node value
        $td->parentNode->replaceChild($th, $td); // replace
        $i--;
    }

}

echo $document->saveHTML();
```

[Doc notes](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php#50500)

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zM3zSl)